# How to write a batch script to loop through logfiles in directory and generate a "filename.found" if i find the string "found" in the log file?

Tags: string, windows, shell, batch-file, findstr

I have a directory "D:\logs" consisting of many log files eg: HRS.log, SRM.log, KRT.log, PSM.log etc.
Each of this log file may or may not have a string "found" inside them. If the log file contains the string "found", then i have to generate "fileName.found" eg: "SRM.found" file in "D:\flags"folder.
i have written the following script but not able to proceed further:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for  %%f IN ("D:\logs\*.log") do (
    findstr /i "found" "%%f" >NUL
    if  "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (
    echo.>"D:\flags\%%f.found"
    ) 
    )
    pause 
    exit /b
)
```

Comment: I think you're going to need delayed expansion on the errorlevel test.

Comment: You're right. thanks for the fix. i've edited the code snippet in the ques. But i still don't understand how to generate a "filename.found" file

Comment: `%%f` is _fully qualified_ path so that `"D:\flags\%%f.found"` isn't a valid path. Use `"D:\flags\%%~nf.found"` or even `"D:\flags\%%~nxf.found"`.

Comment: Yeah! that was what was missing! Thank you @JosefZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%A in (
    '2^>nul findstr /i /m "found" D:\logs\*.log'
) do echo( > "D:\flags\%%~nA.found"
```

`findstr /i` can search in the files for the case insensitive string `found` and use of argument `/m` which allows for return of only the filepaths that contain that string. This can make it more efficient as the `for /f` command returns the filepaths only of interest.

`%%~nA` uses a `for` variable modifier of `n` which is the filename with no extension. View `for /?` for more information about the modifiers available.

Comment: Whilst the question didn't specify whether there should be any content inside the generated `.found` file, I'd probably suggest removing the whitespace character from it. _I often find that `CD.` is useful for that, i.e. `) do cd.> "D:\flags\%%~nA.found"`_

Answer (score 0):

ok, so here's the solution i found for the above question that i asked:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for  %%f IN ("D:\logs\*.log") do (
    find "found" "%%f" >NUL
    if  "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (
        echo.>"D:\flags\%%~nf.found"
    ) 
)
pause
exit /b
)
```

Comment: I have added indentation to your code, to clearly highlight that it has unbalanced parentheses. I'm also going to request that you take a look at the answer which was provided prior to yours, which is almost certainly more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @Compo, yes the prior answer works more effectively